# Voiding a contract for unethical practices

Tags: contracts, legal, contract-cancellation

I'm currently under contract with a US-based company. This company puts me through their training program, and at the end of the program, they market me to clients. I then have to get offered a corporation-to-corporation contract opportunity.

Now, I am new to this, but they are marketing me as someone with five years experience. I didn't know that I would be marketed like this prior to signing the contract, and it isn't mentioned in the contract. Is this unethical? This isn't enough to void a contract, correct?

Also, can anyone attest to the legality of the following contract clauses?

- If I break the contract, I may have to return all monies earned during the training period, and I will have to pay $1000 for each month left on the contract.
- After the contract is over, I cannot work for a company whom I have worked for while under my current contract for a full year. (Legal?)

Comment: Hoo...I can see your conundrum. I don't _think_ that's enough to void the contract, but I'm not a legal expert. Which country is this?

Comment: Context is everything here; which country is this in, and what were the terms of the contract?

Comment: *"If anything is unclear just ask"* -- have you simply applied that to the company? And yes, the non-compete after termination is customary.

Comment: It's a US based contract. The contract states pay rates during training/after training. It doesn't mention "how" I will be marketed to clients or anything

Comment: My point was... have you simply voiced your concerns to the company? It's better to open a dialog than to jump to "You're unethical.. I want out!"

Answer (score 3):

> If I break the contract, I may have to return all monies earned during the training period, and I will have to pay $1000 for each month left on the contract.

I have seen this in other contracts. They want back the money they invested in you. Since I am not a lawyer, I am not sure if this is legal. But I have seen this in many, many contracts. Especially in large companies.

> After the contract is over, I cannot work for a company whom I have worked for while under my current contract for a full year. (Legal?)

Yes. I have seen this as well. I cannot remember how this clause is called right now, but they are limiting you from work in a competing industry for X number of months. I usually see from 6 to 12 months. In our country, they even put 18 months or more years, which I don't find to be legal, but no one has ever tried to prove that on the court.

Comment: Also to add to this, this is unenforceable in the UK; the high court ruled that non-competition clauses cannot be enforced in *Pat Systems v Neilly [2012] EWHC 2609 (QB)* (However, if the company can prove that you are a significant risk to the company if you go elsewhere, or if you know vital company secrets, they **can** enforce this)